# Receiving a ClassCastException when using the AudioFileFormat class' methods

Tags: java, date, audio, mp3, classcastexception

I am working on retrieving the date from an MP3 file so that I can store it as an `int` value. Saying

```
AudioFileFormat format = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(someBufferedInputStreamThatWorks);

Map<String, Object> properties = format.properties();
```

returns a `Map` where calling the `get("date")` method should return `java.util.Date`. After calling

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar()
c.setTime((Date)properties.get("date");
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

I receive a stack trace saying `ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date`. The API documentation for `AudioFileFormat` says that the value associated with "date" is a Date object, but the stack trace says otherwise.

I cannot and will not post the full source, as this is for a school project.

Comment: Even if you couldn't post the real source, you could post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Have you tried printing the value of the property *without* casting it? I agree that the docs make it look like it should be a Date, but if it *is* a string, you could at least potentially parse it...

Comment: Printed it with absolutely no cast, and it was exactly what I need in String form. Thanks many!!